# Java - Regex to replace Octal value in string

Tags: java, regex, ascii, octal

I have set of octal values say (0177-0377). whenever these value I found in string, have to replace with ?.

```
    String a= "sccce¼»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕerferferfer";
    for (int i = 0177; i<= 0377 ; i++)
    {
        char x= (char) i;
        a= a.replaceAll(Character.toString(x), "?");
    }
    System.out.print(a);
```

but this looks good when we have small file but I have to perform this operation in 1TB file.

How we can use regex to achieve this task.

Comment: The literals "177" and "377" aren't octal literals - they're decimal literals. If you want octal values, use 0177 and 0377. It's also not clear why you think regular expressions are the solution here...

Comment: What would be the optimal solution for this scenario?

Comment: Well I would use a `Reader`, read a chunk of text at a time (into a char array), then iterate over the char array, replace any values within that range, then write that chunk out to a `Writer`. Repeat until you've read everything in the file.

Comment: Regex also uses loop. It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve. You want to replace octal number, yet you're converting it to character. It's not clear whether you have ASCII only or whole UTF charset. There are so many things unclear/wrong in your question, my head hurts. Please rewrite with clarity on if you want to replace octal string ? or just Unicode characters with given position in octal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex `[^\p{ASCII}]`, which replace all non `ASCII` characters :

```
a.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "?")
```

**Output :**

```
sccce????????????????????????????erferferfer
```

---

You have to find the representation of the octal character in Hexadecimal, from the [link](http://derrel.net/exp/resource/binoctdechex.htm) `0177` is represent by `\x7F` and `0377` is represented by `FF`

For your case you can use :

```
a.replaceAll("[\\x7F-\\xFF]", "?")
```

[**Ideone demo**](https://regex101.com/r/XydRW9/1)

Comment: I think, I am looking for the same approach. Can u pls explain what exactly the functionality of  `[^\\p{ASCII}]` ?

Comment: @Ajay this will replace all non ASCII characters

Comment: Is there any way to replace specific set of octal values.

Comment: @Ajay what did you want to replace what did you want to get?

Comment: I want to replace octal value range from 0177-0377 with ? as I mentioned in question

Comment: check my answer @Ajay hope this can help you

Comment: Awesome... so for `[0177-0377], [0030-0034]`, regex would be 'a.replaceAll("[\\x7F-\\xFF, \\x18-\\x1F]", "?")' . Please correct if regex is wrong.

Comment: yes @Ajay if you have two range you can also use `|` or operator like this [\\x7F-\\xFF]|[\\x18-\\x1F] or either your solution will work

Comment: How we can replace ASCII characters ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this to the whole file in one go - you need a streaming approach. I'd do something like this:

```
// TODO: Rename to something more appropriate
public static void replaceInvalidCharacters(Reader reader, Writer writer) {
    char[] buffer = new char[16384]; // Adjust if you want
    int charsRead;
    while ((charsRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < charsRead; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] >= 0177 && buffer[i] <= 0377) {
                buffer[i] = '?';
            }
        }
        writer.write(buffer);
    }
}
```

So you'd open a reader (with the appropriate encoding) for the current file, a writer (with the appropriate encoding) for the output file, then call the method above. It will read a chunk of data at a time, replace all the "bad" characters in the chunk, then write the chunk out to the writer.

No need for regular expressions.

Note that there are plenty of non-ASCII characters outside that range though - if you really want to remove all non-ASCII, you'd basically want

```
if (buffer[i] > 126) // Or 127; what do you want to do with U+007F?
```